# Remote Control Unit for HP Pavilion DV6000

Tags: windows-xp, remote-control

Can the DV6000 HP Pavilion laptop remote control be used on Windows XP? (Downgraded from Vista)

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine as long as you find all the right drivers for Windows XP.

I downgraded form Vista to XP several years ago with my HP DV6000 series laptop and once I found all the right drivers everything worked perfectly.

I followed [those](http://www.nogodforme.com/HPDV6500T.htm) instructions while downgrading. The hardest part was finding all the right drivers but the provided link has most of them. They might be outdated but you should be able to find the most recent ones.